# ¿Còmo obtener información de diferentes apps de django?

Tags: django

Dentro de la estructura de mi proyecto tengo dos aplicaciones (AppA y AppB), cada una con un archivo models.py

Dentro del archivo AppA/views.py quiero mandar a llamar unos datos de AppB

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from .models import Reporte

def index(request):
```

**from .models import Reporte** lo estoy obteniendo de AppA/models.py ¿Cómo puedo obtener datos de AppB/models.py y mandarlo a llamar dentro de AppA.views.py? Mi intención es mandar a llamar datos de AppB dentro del template de AppA

Answer (score 0):

Prueba a incluir en views.py de la AppA

```
from AppB.models import nombre_modelo
```

Podrás utilizarlo como otro modulo más.